# Conflicting CSS Coding For Post Images

Tags: html, css, blogger

I had entered the following piece of css coding in my blog template to give a certain width value to all my post images. Essentially I wanted my post images to stretch the full width of the post container so everything looked uniformed.

```
.post-body img {
float: left;
width: 683px;
height: auto;
}
```

However the problem that has come about is that the share buttons at the end of the post have all changed to that width also, which I do not want. How do I change the width of my post images without that piece of coding altering the values for any other images in the post.

Comment: Does your share buttons have some common css class or are in the container that you can target by class or id?

Comment: I have solved the share button image problem but since I put that piece of coding in my template, two other things have been "changed". I want my text-align to be right and not left but the share buttons appear on the left and I cant seemed to change the padding between each of the icons. Below I have included the css coding for the share buttons. hope you can help. .sharebtns {  
text-align: right;
margin: 5% 0% 0% 0%; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
} 
.sharebtns a { 
padding: 0px 10px; 
} 
.sharebtns a img {
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a sample of your html code that displays the problem that you are encountering?  It would help to diagnose your problem much more easily.

Answer (score 0):

A sample of the HTML in question would be beneficial. As @Adam says, it sounds like your share buttons can also be targeted with your CSS selector. If the share button images have another class on them, then you could amend your selector to something like `.post-body img:not(.share-img)`.